# Coding summation i > j in networkx

Tags: python, gurobi

I am using networkx (and gurobi) to calculate shortest path between nodes in a set of nodes. However I need to calculate the summation of all shortest paths in a particular way that is,

Sum for all i > j of dij

where dij is shortest path between node i and j

```
grb.quicksum(nx.shortest_path_length for i > j in g.edges)
```

I think this is very wrong.

Comment: So... do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why you are using both gurobi and nx.short_path_length. networkx's shortest_path_length() and python's sum() is all you need:

```
import itertools as it
import networkx as nx
...
G = nx.Graph()
...
# Define edges of G ...
...
sum(nx.shortest_path_length(G,i,j) for (i,j) in it.combinations(G.nodes(),2))
```

This assumes there is a path between any two nodes of graph G. If not, we get something like:

```
NetworkXNoPath: No path between 1 and 7.
```

gurobi's quicksum() is used to sum up gurobi variables, which are then passed into a gurobi model as a constraint or objective function.